# WooCommerce shortcode show only products by specific text

Tags: hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to show products with WooCommerce shortcode that have a specific text inside.

I use this code but didn't works. `[products products per_page="4" columns="4" s="text"]`Any help? Or some other way?

Comment: It would also be useful to ask here as well: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ as it is the main Wordpress community

Comment: Yes i see it after i post it. Thanks

Comment: Sure no prob :)